# Opening curly brace fails to indent consistently

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, ide

I'm transitioning to Visual Studio 2010 from version 2008 and have noticed several differences between the editor.  Most I have fixed or found work-arounds for.  One feature that I cannot get to work like it did in 2008 is when I type an open curly brace "{" on a non-empty line in a CPP file.  Typically, after starting a for, if, while, or similar statement, I'll automatically type the {} on separate lines below the statement so that the curly braces are nicely lined up (it's an OCD thing).  VS 2010 does what I want in this situation.

```
if (varIsTrue)
{
    varIsTrue = false; // typed after the initial {} pair.
    // do something really innovative here...
}
```

It's when I forget that initial "{" that the editor no longer wants to help.

```
if (varIsTrue)
    varIsTrue = false;
```

Oops.  Forgot the curly brace (or I simply need to create a code block for additional code.)

Typing a "{" gives

```
if (varIsTrue)
    {varIsTrue = false;
```

instead of

```
if (varIsTrue)
{varIsTrue = false;
```

so that hitting ENTER will properly indent "varIsTrue = false;"

Visual Studio 2008 handled this correctly, but 2010 does not.  I've yet to find a way fix this in the editor options, and I assume that an editor extension would be the only other option.

So basically, if there is a way to fix this in the editor, how can I do it?  If not, does an extension exist that would allow me to fix the problem?

Interestingly, this problem does not exhibit itself in a C# file, so I am hoping there is a way to fix it for CPP files.

I appreciate any help regarding this.

Comment: Why not go for Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: @Alf: I just got through reading the various restrictions for using the free version of VS 2015.  Unfortunately, my case does not fall into the category of being able to use it, and I have no doubt that since the price tag of the professional version is roughly 3x what it used to be (I was using 2008, remember), that'll be a tough sell.  So... I'm stuck with 2010.  Thanks for bringing up the possibility, though.